# failed to make loop on the variables

Tags: javascript

i am making a toggle between grid view and list view on some blocks but i failed to make loop on the blocks

the onclick function only works on the first block from the four blocks in the html code.

i want the onclick function to work in all the blocks.

how can i make the function works with the for loop

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="buttons">
       <button id="grid">Grid</button>
       <button id="list" class="disable">List</button>
     </div>
     <div class="blocks" id="blocks">
       <div class="block list">
         <h2>Block 1</h2>
         <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
          sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </p>
       </div>

       <div class="block list">
        <h2>Block 2</h2>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
         consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
         sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="block list">
        <h2>Block 3</h2>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
         consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
         sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="block list">
        <h2>Block 4</h2>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
         consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
         sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
var grid_btn = document.getElementById('grid');
var list_btn = document.getElementById('list');
var blk = document.querySelectorAll('.blocks .block');
var blk_count = blk.length;



grid_btn.onclick = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < blk_count; i++){
        var bk = blk[i];
        bk.classList.add("grid").remove("list");
    }
}

list_btn.onclick = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < blk_count; i++){
        var bk = bl[i];
        bk.classList.add("list").remove("grid");
    }
}
```

Comment: `blk[i]` not `blk(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an array element (subscripting) is done with square brackets (`[]`), not parenthesis (`()`):

```js
var bk = blk[i];
// Here-----^-^
```

Comment: it worked only on the first block... still the loop not working

Answer (score 0):

You might simplify your efforts by using .forEach(); here's the javascript:

```
var grid_btn = document.getElementById('grid');
var list_btn = document.getElementById('list');
var blk = document.querySelectorAll('.blocks .block');

grid_btn.onclick = function(){
    blk.forEach(function(item, index){
        item.classList.add("grid");
        item.classList.remove("list");
    });
}

list_btn.onclick = function(){
    blk.forEach(function(item, index){
        item.classList.add("list");
        item.classList.remove("grid");
    });
}
```

I also had issues with chaining .remove() on the classlist, and I'm not sure that's supported (though admittedly didn't look). Separating that to another line eliminated the errors I was getting.

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/us7tayvp/3/

Comment: Sure thing! Best of luck.